# How can i insert data to mysql database with image name which will be auto upload image without submit and instant display

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

My code is below

View

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/setup_con/add_user_info">
Picture <input name="userfile" type="file" />
Name <input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '800';
$config['max_width']  = '184';
$config['max_height']  = '142;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
echo $error;
}
else
{

$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$img =  $data ['upload_data']['file_name'];

$data = $this->setup_model->add_user_info($img);
}
```

Model

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$img = $img
$data = array (
     'img' =>$img,
     'name' =>$name
    );
$this->db->insert('user',$data);
```

Normally i can do it

Basically ,i want to do at first auto image upload without submit(may be via ajax) and
instantly display then i will submit then insert data to user table with image name and name.

Please help me how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I have misread your question, but this sounds like a really long way of asking how to preview an image before upload. Here is a way of doing that before you do any upload, you can then do your actual image upload along with your database stuff all together on submit.

**HTML**

```
 <img id="preview_img" src="" />
 <input id='img_upload' type="file" name="userfile" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('body').on("change", "#img_upload", function(event) {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#preview_img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: @MD.ABDULHalim No problem, glad to be of help. I noticed that you hadn't accepted any answers yet on any of your questions. If your question is resolved you should accept the correct answer by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: I gave you,Before i wouldn't know. Thanks again